# Compass warning when watching Foundation 5 folder

Tags: ruby, sass, zurb-foundation, compass

I am using Compass to compile and watch Foundation CSS files. However the changes are either not being applied or something is happening. I tried changing the background of my entire website to test if it was my scss file. But as it turns out it seems to be a problem with either Compass or Foundation.

Also the following message shows upon initializing compass watch.

```
You're using Sass 3.4 or higher to compile Foundation. This version causes CSS classes to output incorrectly so we recommend using Sass 3.3 or 3.2.

To use the right version of Sass on this project run "bundle" and then use "bundle exec compass watch" to compile Foundation.
```

I still don't get around fixing it with bundle. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from

https://github.com/zurb/foundation-compass-template/blob/master/config.rb#L27-L30

Try downgrading your gem sass to earlier version, maybe: https://github.com/sass/sass/tree/stable_3_2

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [Foundation docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html) under "Creating A Compass Project" where it says

> Until all Sass library's can catch up to Sass 3.4, Foundation will be on Sass 3.2. This means if you have upgraded to Sass 3.4+ and Compass 1.0+ the commands to compile a Compass project have changed slightly.

Then follow the steps below. Basically you now compile with `bundle exec compass watch` instead of  `compass watch`

If you don't have Bundler installed, you can check the [first step](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/getting-started.html) in their new Foundation for apps docs but basically you need to install the gem like this

```
gem install bundler
```

Hope it helps